# passing variables inside a widget add_action

Tags: widgets, actions

Here's my code inside a widget class:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {

add_action('wp_footer', function () { echo $instance['title'] });

}
```

It doesn't output `$instance['title']`. I tried passing the `$instance` parameter in the function, and even tried `global $instance;`, but neither worked.

Comment: did you add your function `widget` to any hook or invoked it?

Comment: It's a part of the widget class I created. Which contains other functions: `function update()` and `function form()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-186):

```
$title = $instance['title'];

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() use ( $title ) {
    echo  $title; 
});
```